# slf4j not interpreting method name in pattern layout

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I'm using slf4j in my application, which runs in a jboss container.  The underlying framework is log4j.

The problem we see is that the method name (%M) and line number (%L) tags in the logging pattern are not being interpreted correctly.

Instead of seeing my method name, I see 'debug' or 'info' - in other words, the method in the log4j or slf4j class.  Similarly, the line number doesn't correspond to the line number in the code - for example all debug entries have a line number of 104.

Here's how a sample appender is configured:

```
 <appender name="catalog-log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
 <param name="File" value="logs/catalog.log" />
 <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%c:%L|%M|%1.1p|%m  %n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
```

and some sample output:

```
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:104|debug|G|Enter populateTariff
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:104|debug|G|adding new tariff = D 
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:104|debug|G|Found Tariff: D 
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:104|debug|G|Exit populateTariff
```

Here's how it should look:

```
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:3250|populateTariff|G|adding new tariff = D 
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:3261|populateTariff|G|Found Tariff: D 
17.07.2013 09:43:07|com.ecommerce.CatalogAPIUnmarshallerXML:3287|populateTariff|G|Exit populateTariff
```

Before we moved from log4j to slf4j, this was working just fine.

Some classes have not been migrated to slf4j, and they are also working - the line numbers and method names are showing up just fine.  So the finger of suspicion points to slf4j.  Or more likely, my config.

We are using slf4j 1.5.8 and log4j 1.2.16

Comment: Still no luck on this?